# ggplot - control line width in points

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, width

I have the following data:

```
d = data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100), w=sample(c(0,1,2), 100, replace=T))
```

I want to plot these data, so the width of each line is given by d$w (ideally in "pt" units). However, I am having trouble doing this with ggplot. In fact, even when d$w is zero, ggplot still draws a line:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line(aes(size=w)) + scale_size_continuous(range=c(0,2))
```

Any ideas for how to fix this? I know I can replace the zeros with NAs, but my greater concern is that the scale itself is incorrect. Is there any way to make plots with line widths that are measured in meaningful fixed units?

Comment: don't put size within the call to aes. try, `ggplot(d, aes(x=x,y=y),size=w) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(0,2))`

Comment: I get this error: Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomLine,  : object 'w' not found

Comment: strange, I copied your code verbatim and I never got this error. `d = data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100), w=sample(c(0,1,2), 100, replace=T))
ggplot(d, aes(x=x,y=y),size=w) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(0,2))`

Comment: My mistake. I added the "size" argument within geom_line(). However, using your proposed solution does not fix the problem. In fact, it looks like all of the lines are plotted with the same width now. Does this work for you?

Comment: nope, it does not work for me either. My mistake, I did not understand the question correctly. Essentially, you require varied line widths to be plotted dependent on the variable value excluding the values that are zero?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution can be to filter the zero values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
d = data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100), w=sample(c(0,1,2), 100, replace=T))

ggplot(d %>%
         filter(w>0), aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_line(aes(size=w)) + 
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(0,2))
```

[image: Plot]